# Cannot update to php 5 to 7 in linux mint?

Tags: nginx, php-7, linux-mint

I just want to update PHP 5 to PHP 7 and I got below error after adding this line "`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`"

> Adding PPAs is not supported

I am using Linux mint 17 and my web server is Nginx. How to fix this? Is there any alternative

Answer (score 0):

To use the `add-apt-repository` you need to install `software-properties-common` or `python-software-properties` , just run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Then run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Alternative methode:

You can add `dotdeb` repository to your `sources.list` then install PHP 7

Follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252674/153195) on U&L.