# LinuxMint debbie install PHP7.4

Tags: php, linux, debian, linux-mint

i'm using `LinuxMint` with this information:

```sh
hi@hiy:~$ uname -a -r
Linux hi 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux

hi@hi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    LMDE 4 (debbie)
Release:    4
Codename:   debbie
```

i think this release of `LinuxMint` based on `Debian` and this following codes doesn't add `php7.4` to repository:

```sh
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates wget
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
```

install `PHP7.4`

```sh
sudo apt install php7.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the ondrej/php which has PHP 7.4 package and other required PHP extensions.
`sudo apt install software-properties-common`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`sudo apt update`
Once you have added the PPA you can install PHP 7.4.

Execute the following command to install PHP 7.4

`sudo apt install php7.4`

Comment: `Adding PPAs is not supported`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089495/cannot-update-to-php-5-to-7-in-linux-mint

Comment: i get this error `E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate`

Comment: before install `python-software-properties` , try `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but the solution is rather simple, if you think about it.
And hopefully this will help others, that come across the same problem.

LMDE 4 (debbie) is a niche product and doesn't have a PHP package specifically defined for it.
But since it uses Debian 10 Buster as underlying foundation, you can simply use the Buster package.

**Solution:** Exchange `($lsb_release -sc)` with `buster` and it will work.

This is also necessary for some other packages, like Docker.